# Can't call Range() method due to undefined value

Tags: excel, perl, win32ole

I've been working on this project for two days now on and off. I decided to learn to program starting with Perl because of all the data manipulation capabilities it offers.

Here's my code followed by my error. I tried to comment it as best I could. Sorry it's hard to read.

I thought declaring my variables inside of the do until loop would allow them to store the value the user inputs it didn't work.

Also, any suggestions on cleaning up my code and helping to cut system resources needed to process?

Also, I tried to format the cells but to no avail. I've commented those lines out. If you could help me get them working that would be awesome, or at least explain why they aren't.

```
#!C:\Perl\bin
#manage IR/SRN/Parts Used
#Written for Zebra
#Author Dalton Brady
#Location Bentonville AR

#use strict;
use warnings;
use POSIX qw(strftime);
use Win32::OLE;
use Win32::OLE qw( in with);
use Win32::OLE::Const 'Microsoft Excel';
use Win32::OLE::Variant;

$Win32::OLE::Warn = 3;    #Die on errors

my @uut = ('VC5090', 'MK2046', 'MK2250', 'MK4900', '@pos'); #different types of units worked on, trying to name the worksheet after one depending on user input have yet to add that func.
my $ref   = strftime '%Y-%m-%d', localtime();    #create the datestamp
my $i     = 0;                                   #increment counter for why loop
my $n     = 0;                                   #increment for do until loop
my $xfile = 'X:\dataTest\data.xls';              #location of excel file
my $book;     #place for the workbook to exist
my $sheet;    #place for the worksheet to exist

#my $ir;        #store IR of uut
#my $sn;        #store serial number of uut
my $ex;         #a place to hold the excel application
my $pu;         #store the number of parts used, to close the while loop
my $row = 2;    #track row in which data will be placed with the do until loop line 56
my $col = 1;
my $uc;         #units completed to be entered monitors how long to keep the loop open
#my @parts;     #store the different parts as a list within an area (to be written to the spreadsheet)
my @talk = ('IR:', 'SN:', '#of Parts Used: ', 'PN:', 'Units Completed: ');

# start an instance of excel

$ex = Win32::OLE->new('Excel.Application');
$ex->{DisplayAlerts} = 0;    #turn off alerts/textboxes/saveboxes

#check to see if excel file exists if yet open it, if not create it
if (-e $xfile) {
    $book = $ex->Workbooks->Open($xfile);
}
else {
    $book = $ex->Workbooks->Add();    #create new workbook to be used because we couldn't find one

    #########SETUP YOUR EXCEL FILE#############
    $sheet = $book->Worksheets("Sheet1");
    $sheet->Activate();
    $sheet->{Name} = "Test";

    #$sheet->Cells("a1")->HorizontalAlignment = x1HAlignCenter;
    #$sheet->Cells("b1")->HorizontalAlignment = x1HAlignCenter;
    #$sheet->Cells("c1")->HorizontalAlignment = x1HAlignCenter;
    $sheet->Columns("a")->{ColumnWidth} = 20;
    $sheet->Columns("b")->{ColumnWidth} = 20;
    $sheet->Columns("c")->{ColumnWidth} = 30;
    $sheet->Range("a1")->{Value}        = "IR Number";
    $sheet->Range("b1")->{Value}        = "Serial Number";
    $sheet->Range("c1")->{Value}        = "Parts Used";
    $sheet->Range("d1")->{Value}        = "Date";

    $book->SaveAs($xfile);    #Save the file we just created
}

do {
    my @parts = "";
    my $ir    = "";
    my $sn    = "";

    print $talk[4];   #ask for how many units user will be scanning or has completed to be scanned
    $uc = <>;

    print $talk[0];   #ask for the IR number
    $ir = <>;

    print $talk[1];   #ask for uut Serial Number
    $sn = <>;

    print $talk[2];   #ask for the number of parts used, to regulate the parts list storage into the @parts array
    $pu = <>;

    while ($i < $pu) {
        print $talk[3];
        my $scan = <>;
        push @parts, $scan;
        $i++;
    }

    #prints a col 2 row
    $sheet->Range($row, $col)->{Value} = $ir;
    $col++;
    $sheet->Range($row, $col)->{Value} = $sn;
    $col++;
    $sheet->Range($row, $col)->{Value} = (join(", ", @parts));
    $col++;
    $sheet->Range($row, $col)->{Value} = $ref;
    $row++;
    $col = 1;
    $n++;

} until ($n == $uc);

# save and exit
$book->SaveAs($xfile);
$book = $ex->WorkBooks->Close();

undef $book;
undef $ex;
```

And here is the error I receive while running the script.

```
Units Completed: 3
IR:94844545
SN:56489149816
#of Parts Used: 1
PN:694198419
Can't call method "Range" on an undefined value at gen1.pl line 86, <> line 5.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: `$sheet` is undefined at line 86. This would appear to be because you don't don't 'set' `$sheet` if this is true: `if ( -e $xfile ) {`

Comment: Never comment out `use strict;`! If strict gives you errors, you should fix them.